# What does "barrocanrolera" mean?

Tags: traducción, definiciones, palabras-raras

In the novel *Los años con Laura Diaz* by top Mexican author Carlos Fuentes there is a word, "barrocanrolera", which is not in the DRAE, the Gran diccionario Larousse, Wiktionary, or Google Translate.

> ... expendios de comida rápida, complejos de salas cinematográficas, la variedad **barrocanrolera** de la gran ciudad de Los Angeles, y sin embargo, en la mente del joven fotógrafo biznieto de Laura Díaz ...

Is this a known word or one Fuentes made up? What could it mean? How might we convey its meaning in English?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a juxtaposition of barroca and rocanrolera

> Barroco as plenty of adornments (luxury)
>
> Rocanrolera as plenty of rock & roll

Comment: Ha! I found this word years ago and never spotted that it was based on "rock and roll"! I wonder what wording they chose in the English translation of the book...

Comment: Actually "Rocanrolero" come from "Rock & Roll'er" which is a synonym of "Roquero" which in turns come from "Rocker" :)

Comment: Indeed, I just checked Google Translate and for "rocanrolero" it gives "rockin"! (-: